# Get only rows of dataframe where a subset of columns exist in another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get all rows of a dataframe (df2) where the city column value and postcode column value also exist in another dataframe (df1).
Important is here that I want the combination of both columns and not look at the column individually.

My approach was this:

```
#1. Get all combinations 
df_combinations=np.array(df1.select("Ort","Postleitzahl").dropDuplicates().collect())
sc.broadcast(df_combinations)

#2.Define udf
def combination_in_vx(ort,plz):
  for arr_el in dfSpark_combinations:
    if str(arr_el[0]) == ort and int(arr_el[1]) == plz:
      return True
  return False

combination_in_vx = udf(combination_in_vx, BooleanType()) 

#3.
df_tmp=df_2.withColumn("Combination_Exists", combination_in_vx('city','postcode'))
df_result=df_tmp.filter(df_tmp.Combination_Exists)
```

Although this should theoretically work it takes forever!
Does anybody know about a better solution here? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a left semi join using the two columns. This will include the rows in df2 where the values in both of the two specified columns exist in df1:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_result = df2.join(df1, ["Ort", "Postleitzahl"], 'left_semi')
```

Comment: You mean `left_semi`

Comment: @blackbishop I thought they're the same?

Comment: Yes, I mean there is no such type `semi` in Spark. It's like outer joins, there is left and right. (thought for semi you can only use `left_semi` in spark)

Comment: @blackbishop I see, thanks for clarifying. Edited to use the correct terminology.

Comment: @blackbishop Oh, I thought you're only talking about the terminology. I think 'semi' works as described in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join)? I admit I'm lazy and never type left_ ;)

Comment: Ah, so they added it in Spark 3. I didn't know about it. I was pretty sure it doesn't exist in [Spark 2.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join). Learned something new ;)

Comment: @blackbishop ah, interesting. I started using Spark in version 3, so wasn't aware of this. Thanks for pointing out anyways! :) Edited to ensure backward compatibility.

Comment: thank you both! this is now > 20min before against < 1 min now. Crazy what the pyspark  implementation of left_semi can do here vs my implementation :)